# How to force KaTexView alignment to right in android

Tags: android

I am developing an offline quiz application which contains mathematics equations and plain texts. However i tried any alignment and direction attributes to force KaTex alignment to right side, i failed. I don't know how to solve this issue.
I already have tried MathJax library, but it is too heavy and incompatible with Persian language. Any suggestion, please tell me.
Thanks.[image: as you all see, my application is a rtl application. Inside the blue rectangle the top part is description of question. And four below parts are the options that just one on of them is the correct choice. Option 1 has inline style, option 3 has display style. The value of options 2 and 4 is Persian language plain text. Im trying to align completely right-side all values, but i can't.]

Comment: Please, edit the initial post and update it with your current layout or code you have tried, so we can help you.

Comment: Please, be more specific. You should provide relevant snippets of code, layouts, etc. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A just want to align right-side those views that they are inside the blue rectangle. Thanks